# Minimization version of matrix p-norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I considered a minimization version of matrix p-norms, defined for a matrix $A$ by

$$
f_p(A)= \min_{x\neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p}.
$$

Notice that $f_p(A) = 0$ if and only if $A$'s columns are linearly dependent.
Therefore $f_p(A)$ can be seen as a measure of the linear independence of $A$'s columns:
the larger $f_p(A)$ is, the more independent $A$'s columns are.

When $p=2$, $f_2(A)$ equals the smallest singular value of $A$ and can be computed by doing SVD. When $p\neq 2$, is there any known algorithm than can compute $f_p(A)$? Or if this problem has not been studied before for the $p\neq 2$ case, is it likely to be of interest?

Comment: The case $p=1$ and the limiting case $p=\infty$ both have very well known solutions.

Comment: @Daniel Robert-Nicoud How to solve $p = 1$? Do you have any reference?

Comment: You should really use some other notation, because this is not a norm.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Thanks for pointing out. Just changed my notations.